# Changes not staged to commit

Tags: github, terminal, repository

[message from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYy5R.jpg)

I get this message and i don't know what to do next, i was trying to upload my projects in github without success.

i did this commands:

[commands i typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk3Lq.jpg)

now i am stuck with Changes not staged and i want that message to be removed as u can see in my commands i tried everything, please help.

Answer (score 0):

From the message in your terminal, you first need to commit changes before pushing it to Github (or reset your changes if you don't want to push it):

Add and commit changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "<place your commit message here>"
git push ...
```